# I need to crop a video from the local storage and put the file in local storage in android is there any simple implementation?

Tags: android, android-studio, local-storage

I need to crop a video from the local storage and put the file in local storage in  android is there any simple implementation?

Comment: refer this https://github.com/VRGsoftUA/VideoCrop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](https://github.com/VRGsoftUA/VideoCrop) library. You can implement it this way

## Usage

1. Include the library as local library project.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.VRGsoftUA:VideoCrop:1.0'
}
```

2. In code you need to start Activityfor result like so:

```
startActivityForResult(VideoCropActivity.createIntent(this, inputPath, outputPath), CROP_REQUEST);
```

3. Then catch result in onActivityResult callback

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == CROP_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            //crop successful
        }
    }
```